# Pressing Escape key while editing comment discard changes without prompt

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-experience

Most of the time this happened to me when adding code-formatting to existing comments, since the backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>) is just below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in my keyboard layout.

It's really frustrating that all the work you've been formulating/thinking while editing the comment will just be discarded when pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> accidentally.

It would be nice to add a prompt if you've made changes then you tried to cancel or maybe removing that functionality since there is already a cancel button.

Comment: Easier solution: Move to Spain. The escape key is on the other side of the keyboard here. And you get to enjoy nice weather and tasty sangrías.

Comment: Related: [Add comment, leave page, lose comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99220/571958)

Comment: I can definitely reproduce this on Firefox Nightly 91.0a1, Linux. Submit a comment, then click “Edit”, add something to the comment, hit `Esc`: the edit gets discarded without a prompt and the edit process is canceled, just like clicking “Cancel”. This doesn’t happen while _composing a new_ comment, but this is also not what the question is about…

Comment: @zcoop98 I am on Chrome / Win 10 and I can repro it. I'm on Chrome version `91.0.4472.77`. Also repro'd on Microsoft Edge / Win 10.

Comment: @10Rep I goofed– I didn't catch that the posts was talking specifically about *editing* a comment. I repro now.

Comment: I don't get it. *Of course* it works this way, this is how it always works when you type something into a dialog box and then press the Esc key: the dialog box is dismissed, and your work/changes are gone. I like this feature; it is useful, consistent, and predictable. If you don't like the Esc key, you could always use a MacBook Pro with the touch bar. :-)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that I imagine a userscript to address this would probably be pretty trivial.

Comment: @zcoop98 not that trivial as you might think :) Once it is out in the wild the users will start complaining the comments are not saved on their iOS/macOS Safari (storage & tracking protection...)

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, that's reasonable but I think the first time you press `Esc` then telling the user: *Press `Esc` again to exit editor* is not hard to implement.

Comment: Also I believe that it is a common standard to prompt the user when there are unsaved changes in a textarea or form field before canceling or navigating away that would result in data loss.